# Why is 1%2 is equal to 1?

Tags: python

I'm confused with the logic of `1% 2` will be 1. Because from what I know **1/2** is **0** so there is no remainder for this.

Comment: Do you know what the modulus operator returns?

Comment: 3/2 is 1 remainder 1. 2/2 is 1 remainder 0. 1/2 is 0 remainder 1. 0/2 is 0 remainder 0.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_operator

Answer (score 5):

1/2 is 0 with a remainder of 1. The % operator returns that remainder.

Comment: what is a lizard doing on this site

Comment: @jamylak Making us all feel like noobs

Answer (score 4):

`%` returns the remainder of `a / b`:

```
>>> 1 % 2
1
>>> 1/2
0
>>> 1 - 0
1
```

Also, the modulo expression can be expressed as:

```
r = a - nq
```

Where q is `floor(a/n)`. So:

```
>>> import math
>>> 1 - 2 * math.floor(1/2)
1.0
```

Comment: Ahh yeah~~ thanks for being patience explaining this stupid question ~

Comment: @ErikaSawajiri Haha, we all have that moment :p

Answer (score 3):

% is the modulo operator. It returns the remainder after dividing the left hand side by the right hand side.  Since 2 divides zero times into 1, the remainder is one.

In general, if a and b are positive integers, and a < b, then a % b == a.

The arguments do not need to be integers, though.  More detail is available from the python reference documentation (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html):

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the ZeroDivisionError exception. The arguments may be floating point numbers, e.g., 3.14%0.7 equals 0.34 (since 3.14 equals 4*0.7 + 0.34.) The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand [2].
>
> The integer division and modulo operators are connected by the following identity: x == (x/y)*y + (x%y). Integer division and modulo are also connected with the built-in function divmod(): divmod(x, y) == (x/y, x%y). These identities don’t hold for floating point numbers; there similar identities hold approximately where x/y is replaced by floor(x/y) or floor(x/y) - 1 [3].

Comment: *"In general, if a and b are integers, and a < b, then a % b == a"*... Not if `a` is negative.

Comment: Good catch.  I corrected the comment on the general case to restrict it to positive integers--given the question's simple example, I wanted to provide something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly there is a remainder.  How many 2s can you get out of 1?   0 of them, with 1 left over.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the answer has been posted like 6 times already, just adding this for completeness, If there's one way to understand modulo (`%`), it's converting from base 10 to base 2, 1 can't be divided by 2 so we leave it alone *(get a remainder of 1)*. You can imagine the binary numbers in the third column to be the results of a modulo operation.

eg. 9 (base 10) to (base 2)..

```
2 | 9 | 1  
2 | 4 | 0  
2 | 2 | 0  
2 | 1 | 1
```

Answer (score 1):

2*0 is 0
hence the remainder is 1

if the question is to find m%n

we find smallest or equal q such that n*(some whole number) = q and q<=m
we then find (m-q) which is the remainder..

Answer (score 1):

What the `%` operator is doing:

`a % b` equals a value `c` such as `0 <= c < b` and there exists a number `k` so that `b * k + c = a`.